# Crear documentos a partir de un formulario

Tags: python, formularios, python-docx

Buen día a todos.

Actualmente estoy aprendiendo a programar en Python; tengo un curso básico (Programming for everybody) y entiendo en términos generales el lenguaje.

**1. Resumen del problema**

Trabajo en una startup donde deseamos implementar un sistema que nos permita:

a. Proporcionar a los usuarios un formulario al que introducir datos.
b. Colocar estos datos en una plantilla previamente creada.
c. Generar un documento personalizado para cada usuario con base en la información que nos hayan proporcionado.

**2. Descripción de lo intentado**

Como señalé al inicio, tengo conocimientos básicos en python, por lo que se me ocurrió lo siguiente:

a) Instalar python-docx para generar el documento.
b) Utilizando el editor Atom, crear el código:

```
documento = input('Indica el documento a generar:')

if documento == 'Ejemplo':

    nom1 = input('Indica el nombre de 1: ')
    nom2 = input('Indica el nombre de 2: ')
    dom1 = input('Indica el domicilio de 1: ')
    dom2 = input('Indica el domicilio de 2: ')

    document = Document()
    document.add_heading('documento', 0)

    p = document.add_paragraph('Se señala que el c. ', 'nom1' 'y el c. ', 'nom2'
    'viven, respectivamente, en', 'dom1' 'y ', 'dom2'.

    document.save('Domicilios.docx')

    print('Documento creado')

else:

    print('Error')
    quit()
```

**3. Muestra algo de código.**

De acuerdo a lo que he realizado en esta etapa temprana de mi formación, no debería ser tan complicado hacer lo que deseamos, sin embargo, no obstante que me parece que el código no tiene errores en cuanto a su sintaxis, obtengo el siguiente error al intentar ejecutarlo:

```
C:\Users\user1\Documents\CG>python Contratos.py
  File "Contratos.py", line 15
    print('Documento creado')
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

La idea es que en algún momento seamos capaces de obtener algo similar a lo que existe en [este sitio web](https://www.rocketlawyer.com/document/business-contract.rl)

Agradezco de antemano la ayuda que me puedan proporcionar y me disculpo si el código es un desastre, recién comencé la carrera de ingeniería en desarrollo de software y de momento sé que tengo más entusiasmo que conocimiento :P

Muchas gracias, @gabrielcoronel y una disculpa al moderador por haber colocado de manera incorrecta la actualización del problema.

El problema que comento se resolvió, sin embargo ahora se despliega el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Contratos.py", line 16, in <module>
    p = document.add_paragraph('Se señala que el c. ', 'nom1' 'y el c. ', 'nom2', 'viven, respectivamente, en', 'dom1' 'y ', 'dom2')
TypeError: add_paragraph() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 7 were given
```

Asumo que tiene que ver con la cantidad de variables que puede admitir add_paragraph(), pero no encuentro información al respecto en la red.

Agradecería mucho una mano aqui :)

Saludos.

EDIT:

Solucionado. Es un tema muy sencillo, pero bueno, estoy empezando con esto y me parece dificil comprender la documentación de python-docx.

Basicamente el problema fue que p = document.add_paragraph se utiliza para señalar un nuevo párrafo; posteriormente se debe usar el comando p.add_run() para añadir el contenido de las líneas de texto dentro de este:

```
p = document.add_paragraph
p.add_run('Se señala que el c. ')
```

Así mismo, para señalar la introducción de una variable, esta debe ir en un run separado, por lo que la forma correcta de escribir mi código fue la siguiente:

```
if documento == 'Ejemplo':

nom1 = input('Indica el nombre de 1: ')
nom2 = input('Indica el nombre de 2: ')
dom1 = input('Indica el domicilio de 1: ')
dom2 = input('Indica el domicilio de 2: ')

document = Document()
document.add_heading('documento', 0)

p = document.add_paragraph()
p.add_run('Se señala que el c. ')
p.add_run(nom1)
p.add_run('y el c. ')
p.add_run(nom2)
p.add__run('viven, respectivamente, en')
p.add_run(dom1)
p.add_run('y ')
p.add_run(dom2)

document.save('Domicilios.docx')

print('Documento creado')
```

Por cierto, se escribe p.add_run() cuando el párrafo está asignado a una variable que denominamos como "p", es decir p = document.add_paragraph(), si nuestro párrafo tiene otro nombre, el run se añadiría con esa variable, por ejemplo:

```
nombre = document.add_paragraph()
nombre.add_run()
```

Espero que a alguien le sirva; a mi me tomó un ratito entenderlo y si hay un error o una forma más sencilla de hacerlo, se agradecería mucho la ayuda.

Saludos a todos.

Answer (score 0):

El problema aquí es que se te olvido poner un paréntesis ()) y en vez de eso pusiste un punto (.). Para ser más especifico en la siguiente linea:

```
p = document.add_paragraph('Se señala que el c. ', 'nom1' 'y el c. ', 'nom2'
    'viven, respectivamente, en', 'dom1' 'y ', 'dom2'.
```

El punto (.) del final debería de ser un paréntesis ()). Te adjunto el código corregido:

**Solución:**

```
documento = input('Indica el documento a generar:')

if documento == 'Ejemplo':

    nom1 = input('Indica el nombre de 1: ')
    nom2 = input('Indica el nombre de 2: ')
    dom1 = input('Indica el domicilio de 1: ')
    dom2 = input('Indica el domicilio de 2: ')

    document = Document()
    document.add_heading('documento', 0)

    p = document.add_paragraph('Se señala que el c. ', 'nom1' 'y el c. ', 'nom2'
    'viven, respectivamente, en', 'dom1' 'y ', 'dom2')

    document.save('Domicilios.docx')

    print('Documento creado')

else:

    print('Error')
    quit()
```